# Run-time error when setting the value of a variable in Python

Tags: python

I want to make an RPG game, and I'm trying to make a system of buying items and potions. What I intended was for the player to get 3 potions of each in the beginning, but you need to buy more to continue with them. My problem is that they keep on resetting every time I call the `fight` function.

I've tried making them global in the beginning and defining them, but they keep on saying "Referenced before assignment"

```py
def Fight(monster):
    global HealPotionsLeft
    global WeakPotionsLeft

    HealPotionsLeft = 3
    WeakPotionsLeft = 3
    Potion = ['Yes', 'No']

    currentFighter = ""

    if myPlayer.dexterity >= monster.dexterity:
        currentFighter = myPlayer.name
    else:
        currentFighter = monster.name

    while myPlayer.isDead is not True and monster.isDead is not True:


        print(currentFighter + "'s turn!")
        print("===========================")
        print("Name:", myPlayer.name)
        print("Health:", myPlayer.health, "/", myPlayer.maxHealth)
        print("===========================")
        print("Name:", monster.name)
        print("Health:", monster.health, "/", monster.maxHealth)
        print("===========================")
        if currentFighter == monster.name:
            monster.Attack(myPlayer)
            currentFighter = myPlayer.name
            continue

        userInput = ""
        validInput = False

        while validInput is not True:

            print("-Attack")
            print("-Spells")
            print("-Items")
            print("-Flee")

            userInput = input()

            if userInput == "Attack":
                myPlayer.Attack(monster)
                break

            if userInput == "Spells":
                print("TO DO - Spells")

            if userInput == "Items":

                secure_random = random.SystemRandom()



                item = secure_random.choice(Potion)

                if  item == ('Yes'):
                    print("You have", HealPotionsLeft, "Potions of Healing Left and", WeakPotionsLeft, "Potions of Damage Left.")
                    PotionUsage = input("Would you like to use your *Potion of Healing*? y/n")
                    if PotionUsage == str("n"):
                        if HealPotionsLeft == 0:
                            print("You spent too much time trying to get the healing potion so you got attacked! *Out of Healing Potions*.")
                            break

                    elif HealPotionsLeft > 0:
                        if PotionUsage == ("y"):
                            myPlayer.health = 100
                            print(myPlayer.name, "Healed to 100 HP!")
                            HealPotionsLeft = HealPotionsLeft - 1

                            PotionsLeft()
                            break
                    if PotionUsage == str("y"):
                        if WeakPotionsLeft == 0:
                            print("You spent too much time trying to get the Potion of Damage so you got attacked! *Out of Potions of Damage*.")
                            break

                    elif WeakPotionsLeft > 0: 
                        weakPotion = input("Would you like to use your Potion of Damage? y/n")
                        if weakPotion == str("y"):
                            monster.health = monster.health - 20
                            print(myPlayer.name, "Used their Potion of Damage on" , monster.name, "for 20 damage!")
                            WeakPotionsLeft = WeakPotionsLeft - 1



                            PotionsLeft()
                            break

                if item == ('No'):
                    print("You didn't get to your potions in time!")
                    break
```

I expect the potions to go to three when the player goes into battle in the first time, but afterwards when going to battle the amount of potions resets the the amount remaining from last battle.

Comment: please correct the indentation

Comment: do you define `HealPotionsLeft` and `WeakPotionsLeft` outside of the function?

Comment: @depperm Yes I have

Comment: please provide more of a [mcve]

Comment: Hi BanCodeMan, please provide full minimal reproducible code example and exact error including line number it refers to. With this information StackOverflowers will be able to better help you.

Comment: Where `myPlayer` came from?

Answer (score 0):

Outside this Fight() function initialize your potion counts to 3 each.  Then pass the current amount of potions in to the Fight() function something like:  `Fight(monster,Hpots,Wpots)` then return the remaining potions to the outer scope with a `return(HealPotionsLeft,WeakPotionsLeft)`

********* Example Requested:  *********

**I can not test this code and this is just an example**

```
BattleResults = []
global CurrentHealPotions
global CurrentWeakPotions

CurrentHealPotions = 3
CurrentWeakPotions = 3


def Fight(monster,HealPotionsLeft,WeakPotionsLeft):

    Potion = ['Yes', 'No']

    currentFighter = ""

    if myPlayer.dexterity >= monster.dexterity:
        currentFighter = myPlayer.name
    else:
        currentFighter = monster.name

    while myPlayer.isDead is not True and monster.isDead is not True:


        print(currentFighter + "'s turn!")
        print("===========================")
        print("Name:", myPlayer.name)
        print("Health:", myPlayer.health, "/", myPlayer.maxHealth)
        print("===========================")
        print("Name:", monster.name)
        print("Health:", monster.health, "/", monster.maxHealth)
        print("===========================")
        if currentFighter == monster.name:
            monster.Attack(myPlayer)
            currentFighter = myPlayer.name
            continue

        userInput = ""
        validInput = False

        while validInput is not True:

            print("-Attack")
            print("-Spells")
            print("-Items")
            print("-Flee")

            userInput = input()

            if userInput == "Attack":
                myPlayer.Attack(monster)
                break

            if userInput == "Spells":
                print("TO DO - Spells")

            if userInput == "Items":

                secure_random = random.SystemRandom()



                item = secure_random.choice(Potion)

                if  item == ('Yes'):
                    print("You have", HealPotionsLeft, "Potions of Healing Left and", WeakPotionsLeft, "Potions of Damage Left.")
                    PotionUsage = input("Would you like to use your *Potion of Healing*? y/n")
                    if PotionUsage == str("n"):
                        if HealPotionsLeft == 0:
                            print("You spent too much time trying to get the healing potion so you got attacked! *Out of Healing Potions*.")
                            break

                    elif HealPotionsLeft > 0:
                        if PotionUsage == ("y"):
                            myPlayer.health = 100
                            print(myPlayer.name, "Healed to 100 HP!")
                            HealPotionsLeft = HealPotionsLeft - 1

                            PotionsLeft()
                            break
                    if PotionUsage == str("y"):
                        if WeakPotionsLeft == 0:
                            print("You spent too much time trying to get the Potion of Damage so you got attacked! *Out of Potions of Damage*.")
                            break

                    elif WeakPotionsLeft > 0: 
                        weakPotion = input("Would you like to use your Potion of Damage? y/n")
                        if weakPotion == str("y"):
                            monster.health = monster.health - 20
                            print(myPlayer.name, "Used their Potion of Damage on" , monster.name, "for 20 damage!")
                            WeakPotionsLeft = WeakPotionsLeft - 1



                            PotionsLeft()
                            break

                if item == ('No'):
                    print("You didn't get to your potions in time!")
                    break

    if myPlayer.isDead is True
        result="You have been defeated!"
    else
        result="You have slain the Beast!"
    BattleEnd=[result, HealPotionsLeft, WeakPotionsLeft]
    return(BattleEnd)
```

A call to this function might look like:

```
BattleResults = Fight("Your Monster Reference Here",CurrentHealPotions,CurrentWeakPotions)
```

Then assign the new values to potions:

```
CurrentHealPotions = BattleResults[1]
CurrentWeakPotions = BattleResults[2]
```

Comment: Can you show me an example on how to do it? Im fairly new to python and i need a bit of help on it. Thanks

Comment: @BanCodeMan example added

Comment: Thanks, Brian. I'll test this out tomorrow.